# Custom commands for URLs

Tags: latex

I would like to create a latex command that adds blue color, underlines it and makes it into true-type font for URLs like this:

```
    \url{stackoverflow.com}
```

However, when using the command `\newcommand` it doesn't work when I do something like this:

```
    \newcommand{\url}{\color{blue}\texttt\underline}
```

Is there a way of still creating my `\url` command in a similar way as in the code described above?

Comment: Just use one of the `hyperref` or `url` packages.

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/26071/how-can-i-have-colored-and-underlined-links-with-hyperref shows how to underline hyperlinks

Comment: Using `\underline` will not allow you to break the URL across lines. Crudely, you're looking for something like `\newcommand{\url}[1]{\textcolor{blue}{\ttfamily\underline{#1}}}`.